# NSMutable addObject problem

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Noob here getting stuck and probably doing something stupid and would appreciate some guidance.

I've declared an NSMutableArray (resultArray) in my .h file, set the @property and @synthesize in the .m file.

In the initWithNibName i'm doing the alloc and init for the array:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
        resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And in one of my methods i'm trying to do an addObject within a for loop, but whatever i try the array does not appear to contain objects (either by using objectAtIndex or count):

```
for (int i=[resultNumber length]; i>0; i--) {   
    NSString *theNumberRes = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[resultNumber characterAtIndex:i-1]]; 
    [resultArray addObject:theNumberRes];
}

NSLog(@"array count: %i", [resultArray count]);
```

I can step through the code and see the code running through the loop as many times as expected, but the NSLog never gives a result other than 0 (and hovering over the resultArray shows 0 objects at all times.  (In brief, each object in the array is supposed to be a character from a string in reverse - e.g. if resultNumber is 12345, the array should store 5,4,3,2,1).

I have seen a number of other questions asking similar questions but they either don't seem to help or i don't understand the answer and didn't want to hijack someone else's question with my question.

Please could someone advise me as to how to get this working?

Comment: That's mostly because `resultArray` is `nil` where the log is called. You can verify this by doing `NSLog(@"%@", resultArray);`. You should also verify if they are the same instance. Try `NSLog(@"%@", self);` in both the methods you've listed.

Comment: @Deepak already called it, your resultArray is most likely not being initialized. How are you instantiating the view? You should put an NSLog in that init method to make sure it is getting invoked.

Comment: How are you creating your UIViewController? Is it coming from a NIB or are you creating it in code? If the latter then can you show us the relevant line of code?

Comment: thanks all, back to the drawing board for me.  initWithNibName is not firing.  I can get the code to work by doing the init in the same method, but then the array is not available in other methods.  i realise i'm missing something obvious here so i'll look into it myself.  thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is if the `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` method get called. There is other initialization routines such as

```
-(id)init; 
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder)aDecoder;
```

If your view is loading from a .xib file there is a possibility, that the last one is called and not the one you are initializing your array in.

Comment: as i mentioned, i'm a noob.  the initWithNibName isn't firing so i've missed something obvious - back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

The `%c` is what is messing you up. Look here

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

That is for 8-bit unsigned characters. If your string contains utf-8 characters, then this will not work. You could maybe use %C or you should use `NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding`